# How to turn on , off sound for MPMoviePlayerViewController

Tags: iphone, ios, ios-simulator

Hey I need to set volume for **MPMoviePlayerViewController** in ios.
I have searched a lot on this but fails. I have got answers to set volume for MPMoviePlayerController,
MPmusicPlayer but not **MPMoviePlayerViewController.**
Please help me. thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you dont need to do it programmatically....the UI of MpMovieplayerViewController  do have volume adjustment as default...why are you trying to do it your own?

ok try this

[[MPMusicPlayerController applicationMusicPlayer] setVolume:];

Will change the device's volume, not the media player's so any other audio or video streams are also affected.

Comment: .Thanks for your reply but i am using MPMoviePlayerViewController programaticaly. and i need to adjust volume programmatically.

Comment: @Raj ok..thats fine..check my edited answer..is this what you need?

Answer (score 0):

try this...

```
 [[MPMusicPlayerController applicationMusicPlayer] setVolume:sliderr.value];
```

it only work in device,not work in simulator

Comment: you check device or simulator ?

Comment: set "0" for OFF,set "1" for ON the volume range is 0-1